# Preventing script injections in HTML form

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a HTML form which essentially searches for posts in WordPress. The markup looks like this:

```html
<form class="resourceFilters__searchForm position-relative" role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/search/'); ?>" method="get">
  <input class="resourceFilters__searchForm-input" type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search" />
  <input class="resourceFilters__searchForm-btn" type="image" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()." /assets/build/vectors/search-icon-bold.svg "; ?>" alt="Submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="p_type" value="Resources" />
</form>
```

In this textfield, I ran a test and tried to search `<script>alert(1);</script>` which executed on search - not ideal.

To prevent `scripts` from being processed in this textfield, I tried the following:

```html
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'intercept_banned_keywords' );

function intercept_banned_keywords ($query) {
  $banned = array ('<script>', 'alert');
  if ( in_array ($query->query_vars['s'], $banned) ){
    $query->s = '';
  }
}
```

But no luck. `scripts` are still parsable in the textfield.

How can I prevent scripts from being allowed / searched in a field?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+prevent+xss

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form you need to sanitize the data.
use `sanitize_text_fiedl()` for text field values.

More details on sanitization: https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/sanitizing/

After the form submissions it goes to siteurl/search. Find out the template used for that page (possibly search.php) and add your sanitization in the code.

Answer (score -2):

Add below code in your function.php file this will disallow the script injection inside the search form.

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 't5_search_escaped_characters', 10, 2 );

function t5_search_escaped_characters( $search, $obj = NULL )
{
    if ( $obj->is_search and empty ( $search ) and is_main_query() )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
        return ' AND 1 = 2 ';
    }
    $s   = $obj->query_vars['s'];
    // Double-encoding FALSE in case another plugin did that already.
    $esc = htmlspecialchars( $s, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE );
    return str_replace( "%$s%", "%$esc%", $search ) . ' ';
}
```